# How do I make the size of a header grow conditionally using CSS?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a web page with a header that remains fixed while the rest of the page scrolls. So great, right now the header is {position: fixed, height: 60px} and we have body {margin-top: 60px}.

We have some responsive design so on a cell phone the header looks a little different, but no big deal, media queries.

Now I need to add a button to the header ... but only when certain conditions for the page are true. But here's where I'm stumped. On wide screens, the button should be on the same row with the rest of the header, inside the present 60px height. But on a cell phone, there's no room, so I need to push the button down to the row below. If the button was always present, okay, I could have a media query that says that when the width is less than whatever make the header height say 90px and body margin-top 90px.

But the button doesn't always appear. How can I write css to make the header height expand when the button is there but not if it isn't?

Comment: Without actual code this is a bit of a wild guess, but why are you setting a hard pixel height? If your CSS is correct your headerbar will always be about 60px (relative) but when more space is needed the button will drop and the header should grow accordingly?

Comment: @ArnoTenkink Part of the answer is that I didn't write the code for the header as is, it's a mess, and when I take out the fixed height it gets bigger for reasons that I don't understand. I spent hours pouring over F12 displays trying to figure it out. :-( But even if I threw out the current code and rewrote it in some sane manner, I'd still have to change the margin on the body on the fly. Which okay, that might be one or two lines of JavaScript: set body.margin-top to the actual height of the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you maybe add a class to your header whenever the button is also present? Then you can do the correct styling based on that class. This can be easily done using js.

Comment: Duh. Excellent idea. I can add the class in the server side code and not even have to dirty my pristine hands with JS.

Comment: Even better! :D

Answer (score 1):

With position fixed it's quite hard to achieve this functionality without the use of JavaScript.

But [most modern Browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) can work with `sticky`

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(63, 63, 191, 0.8);
  color: white;
}

header p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

#pageContent {
  height: 110vh;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p>my Header</p>
  <p>some extra Content</p>
</header>
<div id="pageContent">
  Here be text<br/> and text</br>
  and even more text
</div>
```